# Deleted Netbeans File?

Tags: java, netbeans, recovery

I worked on a Netbeans Project for about an hour this morning, then saved and shut down my laptop. Now I'm trying to access the project again but the main class in my project is empty except for a ton of /u0000 characters. The file size is still 33kb which sounds about right so I'm sort of hopeful that my code is somewhere? When I right click  the project folder and search for deleted files, nothing shows because it wasn't deleted, just overwritten.

Is there a way to recover my work? I have a back up of the code, but its a few hours behind.

Thanks

**Update**: A recovery program tried to restore the file and gave me a new file filled with this stuff when I open it w/ notepad:

```
äOñQ2 ucOñy/ ˆOñ¢Ú êœOñœõ q Oñ—+ f¦Oñz p²OñX ±×Oñ¸ö 0áOñE% _äOñe! åOñ+ ‹Pñï pPñ—- ÀPñ0
```

I don't know if that has any correlation to my old file text.

Comment: If it's a Linux machine have a look in the /lost+found folder of this partition. Because having only zero bytes in the file sound like an unclean shutdown.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I am on windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if there is something in the Netbeans local history.

- open the file you want to get back in Netbeans
- go to menu Team -> History -> Show History

You will get a list of saved revisions of that file. Start with the most recent one to find a revision which contains the latest saved code.

Comment: I am eternally grateful. :D